# How to compare DateTime in MySQL on PHP Separate Date & Time Post

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a column StartTime and EndTime in database and I'm trying to compare Date & Time from a submit in mySQL.

Here is what I've tried:

```
public function checksched(){

        $this->db->where('employee_id', $this->input->post('employee_id'));
        $this->db->where('StartTime <=', $this->input->post('StartDate').' '.$this->input->post('StartTime'));
        $this->db->where('EndTime >=', $this->input->post('EndDate').' '.$this->input->post('EndTime'));
        $query = $this->db->get('maintenance');
        if($query->num_rows() == 1){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: what problem you are facing in this query?

Comment: @Vinie well it did not returned false when actually there is an instance in the database

Comment: maybe there are 2 instances of this in your db try `if($query->num_rows() > 0)` instead

Comment: yes it will give because you are comparing two string use `STR_TO_DATE`